# Should I check "Copy items if needed" in importing GooglePlus.framework?

Tags: ios, google-plus

I'm implementing Google Plus login in my app, should I keep "Copy items if needed" checked when importing GooglePlus.framework, GoogleOpenSource.framework and GooglePlus.bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so that your project is independent as it has its own set of frameworks and stuff.

Alternatively, which is a better way to do it, try [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/).

Comment: alright, I was just wondering cause it will add almost 16mb on my project that will increase my app size. Unlike using Facebook SDK, they clearly specify to uncheck "Copy items if needed".

Comment: The app size will still be the same after you archive it. It's just that your project folder doesn't have to contain it. It will just have a reference to the framework that you store somewhere in your own computer. Also note that if you are working with someone else in a team, the other team members won't be able to run your code if they happen to store their Facebook SDK somewhere else.